# Extremely low fps (graphics lagging) after update

Tags: graphics, display, intel-graphics

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with the 4.8 kernel. This morning I installed updates via Software Updater, and after rebooting my screen is lagging: window open really slowly and progressively, same for terminal. Checking the fps with
 `vblank_mode=0 glxgears` gives me around 30 fps, compared to 7000 on computers around me. 
I have no additional drivers installed, and the results of `lshw -c video` is:

```
   *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-e0ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Does anyone know the cause of this issue, and how to solve it ?

Edit: `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode` gives:
`intel-microcode is already the newest version (3.20180108.0+really20170707ubuntu16.04.1).`
`uname -r` gives: 4.8.0-58-generic

Comment: Where is the 4.8 kernel from? The latest kernel on 16.04 is 4.13. As noted in your `lshw` the intel driver is not being loaded in the kernel, so you are likely in low graphics mode on framebuffer driver. You should make sure `intel-microcode` is installed, along with the latest kernel updates.

Comment: @dobey see my edit. How should I update the kernel ?

Comment: How did you install the 4.8 kernel? It is not a standard kernel that was available on 16.04. Only 4.4, 4.10, and 4.13 have been the officially supported kernel versions on it so far.

Comment: But where did you get the 4.8 kernel from? You built it yourself? You added a PPA and installed it? You should install the `linux-signed-generic-hwe-16.04` and `linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04` packages.

Comment: @dobey I on't remember how I installed it. I followed your instructions and everything is back to normal. Could you include your instructions in an answer so that I mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using an unofficial kernel, so there may be some problems with that build.

You should install the `linux-signed-generic-hwe-16.04` and `linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04` packages to get you back on track with standard Ubuntu kernel updates on your system.